# deleteRecord does not remove record from hasMany

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

When I call `deleteRecord()` on some of my hasMany relations, Ember Data sends a (successful) `DELETE` request, but the record is not removed from the view. I am displaying it using the `render` helper like this:

```
{{render "modules.list" modules}}
```

The interesting thing is that Ember Inspector reveals that after `deleteRecord()` the corresponding object is `<App.Module:ember1182:null>` and its parent is `null`, too. It's parent, however, still shows the record in its `hasMany` (as `<App.Module:ember1182:null>`)  When I reload the page and then call `deleteRecord()`, it is removed from the view as expected.

It seems that `deleteRecord()` does not remove the record from the parent's `hasMany` array. Oddly enough this works fine in other parts of my code. One theory I have is that this has to do with the `{render}` helper, because wherever I use that I have the same issue, but I am not sure if that's what's causing the problem.

I am using the latest build of ember data (`commit 2511cb1f77`).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found the solution. It seems like `deleteRecord` calls `clearRelationships`, which in turn sets the `belongsTo` of the model to `null`. However it does not clear the inverse (i.e. it does not remove the model from the `hasMany` relation of the parent). The following code fixed it.

```
var model = this.get('model');
model.eachRelationship(function(name, relationship){
    if (relationship.kind === "belongsTo") {
        var inverse = relationship.parentType.inverseFor(name);
        var parent  = model.get(name);
        if (inverse && parent) parent.get(inverse.name).removeObject(model);
    }
});
this.get('model').deleteRecord();
this.get('model').save();
```

However in my opinion this should be handled by Ember (Data). It seems like it is (most of the time), since this worked fine in other parts of my code. So likely this situation is some sort of edge case. Any thoughts on what might be going on are much appreciated.

Comment: I'm new to Ember Data but had to save parent after calling removeObject.  @chopper should this be necessary?

Comment: Best guess is you have 2 potential inverse relationships so ember doesn't know which to remove it from... although, in that case, since you're deleteing it it should remove from all, ideally.

Comment: This solution stopped working for me when I migrated to ember-cli, so I asked another question about it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24644902/deleterecord-with-multiple-belongsto-relationships-in-ember-cli  Is this answer still the approach I should try?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that setting the `inverse` parameter in the `belongsTo` relation fixes it without having to clean the relation manually in Ember Data 0.14.

```
App.Item = DS.Model.Extend({
  parent: belongsTo('parent', { inverse: 'items' }) 
});
```

So if you instantiate your child model through it's parent like the following :

```
App.ParentController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  actions: {
    add: function() {
      this.get('items').pushObject(this.store.createRecord('item'));
    }
  }
});
```

Any further call to the created `Item` `deleteRecord` instance method would remove it from its parent relation and remove it correctly from the view.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working JSBin demonstrating the general idea of deleting items : http://jsbin.com/ucanam/1059/edit

Can you post an example of whatever is giving you problems?

Comment: Thanks Jeremy, but I'm pretty familiar with how deleting records work. In fact the setup I have is pretty similar to what you posted. Unfortunately there's no good way for me to put together a fiddle as my case involves communication with my backend. The above is really the best description I can give. It seems that in my case the record is not removed from the parent hasMany array. At the moment I don't even know how to narrow the problem down. Any suggestions for this would be great!