# Ember Data- createRecord in a hasMany relationship

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I am using Ember Data beta2 and I have a hasMany relationship set up.

When creating a child record do I have to use pushObject on the parent's corresponding property?

When looking at the documentation I get the impression that I need to correctly set the record's parent property and save it.

This is how I do it:

```
    addPlugin: function() {
        //get the value
        var title = this.get('newPluginName');
        if (!title.trim()) { return; }

        var plugin = {
            name: title,
            category: this.get('model'),
            url: ''
        };
        var plugin = this.store.createRecord('plugin', plugin);
        plugin.save();

        //clear the text field
        this.set('newPluginName', '');
        $("#new-plugin").blur();
    }
```

I see the newly created record in the Ember inspector in Chrome, it is not dirty, but it is not present in the parent listing and after I refresh it is gone.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What works for me is the following:

```
var child = this.get('store').createRecord('child', {
   name: 'New Child',
   parent: parent
};
child.save();

parent.get('children').addObject(child);
// My backend automatically adds the inverse of relationships when saving     
// the child, so I don't need to save the parent separately
```

I don't know what `addPlugin` belongs to, but if you are creating the children from a ChildrenArrayController you may want to include

```
needs: ['parent']
```

in your controller. And before creating the child and adding it to the parent you will need to call:

```
var parent = this.get('controllers.parent');
```

Comment: This works, I was doing something similar at one point, but adding the child using then() after save(). Does this mean that when you are removing you are doing something like popObject on the parents corresponding property?

Comment: It seems like the latest version of Ember Data is buggy in that regard. I've had the issue that sometimes (though not always) child elements were not removed from their parents relation. What worked for me is patching it up like outlined in my answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806533/deleterecord-does-not-remove-record-from-hasmany). See also [this related issue](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1303) on github.