# Ember-data createRecord with hasMany relationship without saving

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I want to create a new site record. The model looks like:

```
var SiteModel = DS.Model.extend({
    name: attr(),
    ...

    languages: DS.hasMany('language'),
});
```

The `language` property describes in which languages the content of a site can be written. To create the form, I need to create a model in my route. So I want to create a new record, without saving this one to the db:

```
 var WebsitesNewRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
     model: function() {
         return this.store.createRecord('site', {
              languages: Ember.A()
         });
     }
 }
```

That does not work as intended, as I got the following error: `cannot set read-only property "languages" on object: <app@model:site::ember1012:null>>`. Why is the `languages` property readOnly? As far as I know I did not configure that in my model...

---

I know the question [Ember Data- createRecord in a hasMany relationship](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18917199/ember-data-createrecord-in-a-hasmany-relationship), but in my case I don't want to save anything yet (I only want to create the model, so I could use it in my template).

Answer (score 6):

Ember-Data defines `languages` as a read-only property because it doesn't want you to replace the array. No matter if you're saving or not, Ember-Data wants you to add relationships with `addObject` and remove relationships with `removeObject`.

So if you wanted to add a language, you would do this:

```
model: function() {
    var model = this.store.createRecord('site');
    var language = getLanguage();
    model.get('languages').addObject(language);
    return model;
}
```

What you're doing by giving `languages` to `createRecord`, is essentially calling `model.set('languages', Ember.A())`, and Ember-Data doesn't like that.

It's dumb, I know, but that's just how Ember-Data works.

Comment: Thx for the explantion why Ember does mark it as read-only. Setting the languages as you describes here works indeed. But still I got that error. Worse, even if I would only write `return this.store.createRecord('site');` in the model function, the error pops up.

Comment: That could very well be a bug in Ember-Data. Any chance you could create a JSBin that reproduces that problem?

Comment: Any word on if this is an Ember-Data bug? I just encountered this using ember-select-2 and a multi-select which sets a hasMany relationship...

Comment: You certainly might be running into a bug, but I can't say for sure. If you could reproduce it in a JSBin, I (or somebody on the ED team) could probably tell you. Because of the complexity of Ember and Ember Data, it's just too hard to say without being able to reproduce.