# How to removeObjects from hasMany in ember-data

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

I have a Playlist and a Track model, where `playlist` `hasMany` `tracks`.
I am trying to delete all tracks from the model associated with given controller before I add results from the next search.

```
Pg.SearchController = Ember.ObjectController.extend
  queryTerm: ''
  actions:
    search: ->
      apiKey = "__API_KEY__"
      queryTerm = @get('queryTerm')
      @set 'model.title', "Search: #{queryTerm}"
      $.ajax "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&maxResults=50&q=#{queryTerm}&key=#{apiKey}"
      .then (response) =>
        model = @get('model')
        # Remove all tracks from playlist here.
        model.get('tracks').forEach (track) =>
          model.get('tracks').removeObject track
        for video in response.items
          track = @store.createRecord 'track',
            identifier: video['id']['videoId']
            title: video['snippet']['title']
          model.get('tracks').pushObject track
```

I've tried several approaches, but all of them leave some records in the relationship. How do I remove ALL records from a `hasMany` relationship without destroying the objects themselves.

Here is what I tried:

Using `removeObject` with `forEach`:

```
model.get('tracks').forEach (track) =>
  model.get('tracks').removeObject track
```

Using for..in:

```
for track in model.get('tracks')
  model.get('tracks').removeObject track
```

Using `removeObjects` directly on the relationship:

```
tracks = model.get('tracks.content')
model.get('tracks').removeObjects tracks
```

Comment: I think you can just do model.set('tracks', null); Then model.save();

Comment: @borisrorsvort I've tried that as well, but got an error: Cannot set read-only property "tracks" on object. I've also tried model.set('tracks', []); but no luck.

Comment: Maybe you can get inspiratio from the answer (with eachRelationship) on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18806533/deleterecord-does-not-remove-record-from-hasmany

Comment: Sorry to resurrect your question, but I'm having exactly the same problem. Were you ever able to come up with a solution for this?